# deleting the appended data - jquery

Tags: jquery

```
select: function (event, ui) {

        var staffItem = new Object();


        staffItem.StaffId = ui.item.id;
        staffItem.Name = ui.item.name;
        staffItem.Photo = ui.item.image;
        staffItem.Email=ui.item.email;
        staffItem.Mobile=ui.item.mobile;          

              var data = "<div><table width='100%'><tr><td align='right' ><div class='close16'/></td></tr></table><div><table><tr><td rowspan='4' width='50px;'><img src='" + staffItem.Photo + "' Width='48' Height='48'  /></td><td>" + staffItem.Name + " ( " + staffItem.StaffId + " )</td></tr><tr><td><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>" + staffItem.Email + "</td><td>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td><td>" + staffItem.Mobile + "</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div></div> ";
                $('#staffInCharge').css('background-color','#FFAA55');
                $('#staffInCharge').append(data);
```

am using this code to append staff details into a div, and in the close16 class am using a image file(for cross mark to delete the data), if I click the cross mark the appended data should be deleted, how can I do that, and also when I append the new data its appending one by one(below of existing data) i need to append it to the right side, how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting the data, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close16', function() {
    $(this).parentsUntil('div').remove();
});
```

As for appending data, it depends a bit on what your DOM looks like, and exactly what you want to achieve. You might want to have a look at [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) and [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) for controlling exactly where your data is added. Making things appear "to the right side" may be more a question of the styles of the elements you're inserting, than where in the DOM you're inserting them.

`.append` adds content to the bottom of a container as far as *your markup* is considered. Whether or not this is the same thing as items physically appear below previous items in the container depends on the properties of these elements.

If you're adding a DIV after another DIV, then it will, by default, appear below the former, but this has more to do with the element's display-mode than with its position in your code. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VjgpJ/).

If the DIV elements were of a different display mode, for instance `inline-block`, they would appear to the right of the previous element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6nDyR/). Note that the JavaScript doesn't change.

However, if you instead wanted to position your DIVs with `float: left;`, you might find that you wanted to insert the elements not at the bottom of the container, but before a `clear: both`-element, that would always be at the bottom. You would then have to use something like `insertBefore`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LddNM/).

Which exact approach works best for you depends on very many aspects of your markup and styles. Saying that you want something "to the right side" does not provide us with enough information to assist you in this regard.

Comment: thank you so much David hedlund, the deleting is absolutely working fine, am a newbie I dont know how to fix that appeding new datas to the right, can you help me on it

Comment: thanks for ur help, I got some idea, I'll let you know once I completed

Comment: i have a doubt, the deleting of records by clicking the cross mark as u suggested above is working fine, but sometimes when I click that cross mark the whole web is getting blank, what is this issue

Comment: @Shanish: what the code does is to remove the closest parent of `.close16` that matches the selector `div`. If at some places or under some circumstances your markup is different, so that the parent defining the area to be removed is not a `div`, the script would continue to look for `div` elements further up in the DOM, hence removing a greater part of the page. You would need to adjust this according to the new spec of what defines a region to be deleted, by changing the selector to perhaps `div,p` or `.close16-container`.

Comment: thanks David for your response, I cant understand fully but got some point and reason, thanks alot

Comment: @Shanish: if you change `$(this).parentsUntil('div').remove();` to something like `$(this).parentsUntil('div').css('background-color','red');` the delete button will not delete, but highlight the area that would be deleted. You could do this change for debugging purposes, and whenever it highlights a too big area, use the browser's inspection tools to find out why the highlighted div is the closest parent div of your `.close16`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataObj = $(data)
$('#staffInCharge').append(dataObj);

$("#crossMark").bind('click', function() { dataObj.remove();});
```

for multiple entries see the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QMx8y/9/

Comment: thanks gabitzish, its working fine for the single entry in the div, but for the case of more than one, all the records are deleted if delete any

Comment: You want to associate each data entry with a different crossMark?

Comment: all your data entries sould have a class (eg: .entry) and all your crossMarks sould have a class (eg: .entry). Now you want to set each coresponding pairs an attribute . I'll edit my post to give an example

Comment: thanks gabitzish, I shall try, If you give coding example I can understand easily

Comment: The coding example was posted 21 hours ago, i've edited my post : http://jsfiddle.net/QMx8y/9/

Comment: thanks gabitizish am checking it, I'll let u know if its working for me..thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like that:- 
this is just general idea :-

```
jQuery("#remove").removeAttr("disabled");
jQuery('#mainField').find('tr:last').prev().remove();
jQuery('#mainField').find('tr:last').prev().remove();
```

deal with class

Answer (score 1):

For deleting the data, you could do it like this:
give some Class or ID of div like 
if you hide that click on some link like

```
<div class='hideme'></div>
<a id='clickme'>clickme</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clickme').click(function(){
    $('.hideme').css({'display':'none'});
  })
})
```