# remove appended svg text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Here is my appended svg text:

```
$("#textinArea").append(parseSVG('<text x="' + xtext + '" y="' + ytext + '" id="' + '#text_chaise_' + i + '_' + j + '" font-size="55" data-access="'+access+'" font-family="Verdana" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="Black">O</text>'));
```

After that i wanted to delete this text and clear it from the image/rectangle.

I tried many solutions like :

```
- $("#text_chaise_" + i + "_" + j).empty();              

- $("#textinArea").append(parseSVG('<text x="' + xtext + '" y="' + ytext + '" id="' + '#text_chaise_' + i + '_' + j + '" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="Black"></text>'));

- $("#textinArea").closest("text_chaise_" + i + "_" + j).empty();
```

and i've got no solution to delete this .

whene i use :
 `$("#textinArea").empty()` it deletes all the texts that are appended to `textinArea` and its not what I want.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588260/how-to-remove-an-appended-element-with-jquery-and-why-bind-or-live-is-causing-el and also this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888774/deleting-the-appended-data-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try it as a by-reference object?

```
var myText = parseSVG('<text x="' + xtext + '" y="' + ytext + '" id="' + '#text_chaise_' + i + '_' + j + '" font-size="55" data-access="'+access+'" font-family="Verdana" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="Black">O</text>');
$("#textinArea").append(myText);

// Delete it by reference
delete myText;
```

A `delete` will delete any dom elements, and maybe this will also work on svg elements. But I'm not sure.